# I wanted to make a javascript library function is not working

Tags: javascript, function, call

I wanted to call the run function that should call the other and action will be done on the base of element_id

```
 NGL = {}
NGL.SceneBuilder = function() {

  var yamlFile = 'http://example.com/main.yaml'
  var parseYaml = function() {
  }
  var buildScene = function() {
    // other code

    simulationStarted(element_id);
  }

  return {
    run: function(element_id) {
      parseYaml();
      buildScene(element_id);

    }
  }

}
NGL.SceneBuilder.run('#someid');
```

Comment: It's not the problem, but your code is falling prey to *The Horror of Implicit Globals* by not declaring `NGL`. Always declare your variables.

Comment: This construct is a little strange. Are you parsing the common yaml file every time you call `run` ?

Comment: `NGL.SceneBuilder` is a **function**. It doesn't have a method `run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing your factory so `NGL.SceneBuilder` is a function, not an object having the `run` property. Call the function :

```
NGL.SceneBuilder = (function() {

  ...

})(); // <<===
```

Note also that you forget to declare the `element_id` parameter in `buildScene` but maybe is it just for the question.